# Quadrilateral with given angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

We are looking for angles x and y.

I have found the values of the following angles:
BEA = 74,
BDA = 64,
ACD = 68,
ECD = 112,

plus the relationship $x+y = 68$.

All other angles equations, from triangles or the sum of angles in the quadrilateral (360) end up in the same equation!

I have found through Geogebra that $x=18$ and $y=50$ but I can't figure out a second relationship to determine them geometrically!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for the proof by elementary geometry, please see Hiroshi Saito(斉藤浩)'s great work about generalized Langley's problem
( https://www.gensu.co.jp/saito/challenge/pdf/3circumcenter_d20180609.pdf ). He introduced the amazing skill named "3 circumcenter method" invented by Ms. aerile_re(pen name), and you can find the solution of this problem in the article (Q1).

Comment: Although it is impossible for me to follow this solution, it is indeed the geometrical solution to the problem! Thank you lchungchen!

Answer (score 2):

my geometric solution:
http://www.davdata.nl/math/geopuzzle28.html

[arc calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQSOT.jpg)

[arc calculation(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEzHs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A proof by Sine Law goes as follows:

Considering triangles $AED, BED, ABD, ABE$:

\begin{align}
\frac {\sin y}{AD} &= \frac {\sin 48^\circ}{ED}\\
\frac {\sin x}{EB} &= \frac {\sin 38^\circ}{ED}\\
\frac {\sin 46^\circ}{AD} &= \frac {\sin 64^\circ}{BA}\\
\frac {\sin 22^\circ}{EB} &= \frac {\sin 74^\circ}{BA}\\
\end{align}

Equating $ED$ in the first two equations we have:

$$\frac {EB \sin 38^\circ}{\sin x} = \frac {AD \sin 48^\circ}{\sin y}$$

$EB$ and $AD$ can be expressed in terms of $BA$:

$$\frac {AB \sin 22^\circ \sin 38^\circ}{\sin 74^\circ \sin x} = \frac {AB \sin 46^\circ \sin48^\circ}{\sin 64^\circ \sin y}$$

Noting that $x = 68^\circ - y$,

$$\frac {\sin 22^\circ \sin 38^\circ}{\sin 74^\circ (\sin 68^\circ \cos y - \cos 68^\circ \sin y)} = \frac {\sin 22^\circ \sin 38^\circ}{\sin 74^\circ \sin (68^\circ - y)} = \frac {\sin 46^\circ \sin48^\circ}{\sin 64^\circ \sin y}$$

Rearranging:

$$(\sin 22^\circ \sin 38^\circ \sin 64^\circ + \sin 46^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 74^\circ \cos 68^\circ) \sin y = \sin 46^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 74^\circ \sin 68^\circ \cos y$$

Giving the expression for $\tan y$:

$$\frac {\sin 46^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 74^\circ \sin 68^\circ} {\sin 22^\circ \sin 38^\circ \sin 64^\circ + \sin 46^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 74^\circ \cos 68^\circ}$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan+%28%28sin+46+sin+48+sin+74+sin+68%29%2F%28sin+22+sin+38+sin+64+%2B+sin+46+sin+48+sin+74+cos+68%29%29) says it is $50^\circ$. One could probably reduce the expression above, but right now I don't see how.

Answer (score -1):

Sinx / Sin(x + 64) = Sin38 / Sin84 *Sin22 / Sin48

Multiply both denom and nom by 4Sin82

Sinx /Sin(x + 64) = 4Sin22*Sin38*Sin82 / (Cos6*Sin48*Sin82)

(4Sin22*Sin38*Sin82 = Sin66 REPLACEMENT)

Sinx / Sin(x + 64) = Cos24 / (4Sin48*Cos6*Sin82)

Sinx / Sin(x + 64) = 1 / (8Sin24*Cos6*Sin82)

(2Sin24*Cos6 = Sin54 REPLACRMENT)

Sinx / Sin(x + 64) = 1 / (4Sin54*Sin82)

(1/4Sin54 = Sin18 REPLACEMENT)

Sinx / Sin(x + 64) = Sin18 / Sin82

X = 18

Y = 50